# Trying to Printf Linked List nodes in C - prints only last node?

Tags: c, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list, definition

**I have a simply linked list array of nodes.**

**I insert a bunch of elements in the list.**

In the **printList()**, the while loop just prints the last node in the list infinitely. But why??

Is the logic wrong? I am asking to print as long as head value is not NULL? I've tried printing next node as its created, it prints. But for some reason, the function doesn't work. Any ideas

```
    #include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct process
{
    int data;
    int burst;
    struct process *next;
} node;

node *head = NULL;

void insert(int data, int burst);
void printList();

int main()
{

    insert(1, 100);
    insert(2, 200);
    insert(3, 300);
    insert(4, 400);
    printList();

    return 0;
}

void insert(int data, int burst)
{
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    if (head == NULL)
    {
        temp->data = data;
        temp->burst = burst;
        temp->next = NULL;

        head = temp;
        // printf("\n\n Head = %d burst = %d\n", head->data, head->burst);
    }
    else
    {
        // // ref the first element
        temp = head;
        // // change the head with the new element data
        head->data = data;
        head->burst = burst;
        head->next = temp; /* add the prev first element to the next */

        // printf("\n Next = data = %d burst = %d\n", temp->data, temp->burst);
    }
}

void printList()
{
    printf("printing...");

    // print the rest elements
    while (head != NULL)
    {
        printf("\nNext = %d  burst = %d\n", head->data, head->burst);
        head = head->next;

    }
}
```

Comment: With `temp = head;` in the `else` part you loose the memory just allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code snippet within the function insert

```
else
{
    // // ref the first element
    temp = head;
    // // change the head with the new element data
    head->data = data;
    head->burst = burst;
    head->next = temp; /* add the prev first element to the next */

    // printf("\n Next = data = %d burst = %d\n", temp->data, temp->burst);
}
```

does not make sense and has a memory leak because the address of the allocated memory was assigned to the pointer `temp`

```
node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
```

and then the value of the pointer was overwritten

```
    temp = head;
```

So the address of the allocated memory is lost.

Rewrite the function the following way

```
void insert(int data, int burst)
{
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));

    temp->data = data;
    temp->burst = burst;
    temp->next = head;

    head = temp;
}
```

It is even better if the function will return a value that signals whether the memory allocation for the new node was successful.

For example

```
int insert(int data, int burst)
{
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    int success = temp != NULL;

    if ( success )
    { 
        temp->data = data;
        temp->burst = burst;
        temp->next = head;

        head = temp;
    }

    return success;
}
```

The function printList is also incorrect because it changes the global variable head. You should introduce an intermediate variable instead of using head.

```
void printList()
{
    printf("printing...");

    // print the rest elements
    for ( node *current = head; current != NULL; current = current->next )
    {
        printf("\nNext = %d  burst = %d\n", current->data, current->burst);
    }
}
```

Take into account that it is a bad idea when functions depend on a global variable. For example you are unable to use two lists in one program.

Comment: Ah thanks! New to C and Linked List, so I'd appreciate if you could clarify: when I assigned temp = head; I lost the malloc memory - right, but is that the reason why the while loop is  printing the last element only? Or the issue was by printList was the reason - or both? thanks!!

Comment: @Shaz After these statements temp = head; and head->next = temp; there is only one element head in the list that points to itself.

Answer (score 1):

Because your insert is wrong. `temp = head` ? You've just leaked the node you malloced and then `head->next = temp` points "next" to "self".